# Using CCTouchDispatcher Cocos2d 2.0 Beta-2 ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, joystick

I am creating a game with cocos2d 2.0 BETA 2.0 [The newest one]. And i need to add a joystick in other class. so I call this "CCTouchDispatcher" in my second class. But I can't call like this:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

So I made this one:

```
_tocuhDispatcher = [[CCTouchDispatcher alloc] init];
[_tocuhDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

But still can't detect the touches. If I enable the  touches in my HelloWorldLayer I could move my object with the touches but no the joystick doesn't work

What could i do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[[director touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

Comment: I will try it, but I already solve it, I take the touch events in my main game and transfer them to my nsobject