# sharedDispatcher is missing from CCTouchDispatcher (Cocos2D 2.0 beta2), what should I use instead?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

When I try to call `[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher];`, it shows an error that the class method sharedDispatcher is missing. I go to the .h file of CCTouchDispatcher and found that sharedDispatcher is really missing! I am using Cocos2D 2.0 beta2. Is it removed from this version? If so what should I use to replace it. (may be `[[CCTouchDispatcher alloc] init]`)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059809/467588. You have to use this instead...

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher]
```

I will still post this question anyway because that one's title is not comprehensive and hard to search, or until its owner accept my edit :)

Answer (score 4):

Same applies to Cocos-2D-X 2.0

pre 2.0: 
    CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher();

since 2.0: 
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher();

Simple, once you've figured it out... ;)